# How can I search through an Expect variable

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm working on an expect script that connects to a switch and then shows the configuration for an interface. I then analyze this output to check for certain things. I would like to store the output of one of the things that I'm checking, which I'm trying to accomplish by searching through $expect_out(buffer), although I'm having a difficult time finding out how to do this.

How should I go about doing this?

The script looks like the following (cut out unnecessary stuff):

```
send "show running-config interface $intf\r"
log_user 0
expect "#"
if {[string match "*service-policy input Access-Port*" $expect_out(buffer)]} {
    set servicepolicy "yes"
} else {
    set servicepolicy "no"
}
if {[string match "*mls qos trust dscp*" $expect_out(buffer)]} {
    set mlsqos "yes"
} else {
    set mlsqos "no"
}
if {[string matc "*Description*" $expect_out(buffer)]} {
    EXTRACT DESCRIPTION STRING FROM $expect_out(buffer)
}
```

This is what the output of $expect_out(buffer) would typically look like:

```
Current configuration : 559 bytes
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/17
 description blablabla
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan xxxxx
 no logging event link-status
 authentication event fail retry 0 action authorize vlan xxxxx
 authentication event no-response action authorize vlan xxxxx
 authentication host-mode multi-domain
 authentication port-control auto
 authentication violation restrict
 mab
 no snmp trap link-status
 dot1x pae authenticator
 dot1x timeout tx-period 5
 dot1x timeout supp-timeout 10
 no mdix auto
 spanning-tree portfast
 service-policy input Access-Port
end
```

The "EXTRACT DESCRIPTION STRING FROM $expect_out(buffer)" line is the part that I am trying to figure out. I know how to split the line up to grab just the description, but i just do not know how to extract the line itself from the buffer variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`regexp`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm) command with the `-line` option:

```
% regexp -line {^\s*description (.*)$} $expect(buffer) -> desc
1
% puts $desc
blablabla
```

I assume the description is not multi-line.

Also, if you just need a boolean value,

```
set servicepolicy [string match "*service-policy input Access-Port*" $expect_out(buffer)]
```

or, do this

```
set servicepolicy [expr {[string match "*service-policy input Access-Port*" $expect_out(buffer)] ? "yes" : "no"}]
```